# Laravel unauthorized page when ajax send request

Tags: laravel, authentication, unauthorized

[image: unauthorized page]

I'm making web based game. The game need to login first, so I use laravel auth::register and auth::login as usual, and add middleware auth to every pages except login&register page. 
Then check the game status using **smartupdater** if ready or not.

```
$("section").smartupdater({
    url       : urlCheckStatus,
    data      : data,
    dataType  : 'json',
    minTimeout: 2000
}, function(response){
    var gameStatus = response.data.status;

    if(gameStatus === 'start')
    {
        gameOn();
    }
    else if(gameStatus === 'active')
    {
        pleaseWait();
    }
    else if(gameStatus === 'stop')
    {
        backToMenu();
    }
});
```

**Register** and **login** function

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('username');

    $user = new User;
    $user->name     = $request->input('username');
    $user->email    = $name.'@abc.com';
    $user->password = bcrypt(Carbon\Carbon::now());
    $user->grade    = $request->input('grade');
    $user->numb     = $request->input('numb');
    $user->save();

    Auth::login($user, true);

    return redirect('menu');
}
```

**check game status** function

```
public function checkGameStatus()
{
    $game_id = Request::input('game_id');
    $data    = Game::find($game_id);

    return response()->json([
        'data'  => $data
    ]);
}
```

But sometimes I was thrown to login page, because error 401 Unauthorized. Trying to console log like the image above.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code how you login and register the users?

Comment: And can you show us what the response is of you ajax call.

Comment: @thefallen this game is simple, I just need their name to store to db and get their name easily from db.

Comment: @ThomasVanderVeen check game status function will return game status which game I requested

Comment: @AnthonyDekoci Hard to see your problem. However I can see your application polls every 2 seconds. If this project will have many users you eventually will get perfromance problems. Maybe it would be a good idea to look into [websockets](http://socket.io/). It's fun and not hard to set up.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Javascript for authorization with Laravel, as per Laravel documentation for API Authentication with Javascript:

> If you are using a different JavaScript framework, you should make
>   sure it is configured to send the X-CSRF-TOKEN and X-Requested-With
>   headers with every outgoing request.

Can you ensure X-CSRF-TOKEN and X-Requested-With are always present in your headers.